# Entity Framework 6 - SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.Course'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create a database when it does not exist, but I am getting this error:

> SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.Course'

This error is happening in the `SaveChanges` method call in my seed method:

```
protected override void Seed(CollegeDbContext context)
{
     _courses.ForEach(_ => context.Course.Add(_));
     _subjects.ForEach(_ => context.Subject.Add(_));
     _teachers.ForEach(_ => context.Teacher.Add(_));
     _students.ForEach(_ => context.Student.Add(_));

     context.SaveChanges();
}
```

My initializer it's been called on the `Application_Start()` using the `Database.Initializer`:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<CollegeDbContext>());
```

It was implemented like that, the seed method it was not called so I called in the constructor.

```
public class CollegeInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<CollegeDbContext>
{
    private List<Student> _students;
    private List<Teacher> _teachers;
    private List<Subject> _subjects;
    private List<Course> _courses;
    private CollegeDbContext db;

    public CollegeInitializer()
    {
        db = new CollegeDbContext();

        if (db.Course == null) 
            return;

        _students = GetMorningStudents().Concat(GetEveningStudents()).ToList();
        _teachers = GetEveningTeachers().Concat(GetMorningTeachers()).ToList();
        _subjects = GetSubjects();
        _courses = GetCourses();
        
        SetStudentsSubjects();
        SetTeachersCourses();

        Seed(db);
    }
}
```

I am even specifying the table name in the `OnModelCreating` method.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    var courseModel = modelBuilder.Entity<Course>();
    courseModel.HasKey(_ => _.CourseId);
    courseModel.HasMany(_ => _.Subjects).WithRequired(_ => _.Course);
    courseModel.HasMany(_ => _.Students).WithRequired(_ => _.Course).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    courseModel.HasMany(_ => _.Teachers).WithMany(_ => _.Courses);
    courseModel.ToTable("Course");

    var subjectModel = modelBuilder.Entity<Subject>();
    subjectModel.HasKey(_ => _.SubjectId);
    subjectModel.HasMany(_ => _.Students).WithMany(_ => _.Subjects);
    subjectModel.HasRequired(_ => _.Teacher);
    subjectModel.HasRequired(_ => _.Course).WithMany(_ => _.Subjects);
    subjectModel.ToTable("Subject");

    var studentModel = modelBuilder.Entity<Student>();
    studentModel.HasKey(_ => _.RegistrationNumberId);
    studentModel.HasMany(_ => _.Subjects).WithMany(_ => _.Students);
    studentModel.HasRequired(_ => _.Course).WithMany(_ => _.Students).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    studentModel.Property(_ => _.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(20);
    studentModel.ToTable("Student");
    //studentModel.Map(_ =>
    //{
    //    _.MapInheritedProperties();
    //});

    var teacherModel = modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>();
    teacherModel.HasKey(_ => _.TeacherId);
    teacherModel.HasMany(_ => _.Courses).WithMany(m => m.Teachers);
    teacherModel.Property(_ => _.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(20);
    teacherModel.ToTable("Teacher");
    //teacherModel.Map(_ =>
    //{
    //    _.MapInheritedProperties();
    //});
}
```

So if am using the `IfDoesNotExist` it should be created, am I doing this wrong?

Comment: First thing to check: was the datebase newly created or did it already exist having the wrong or no) tables?

Comment: @GertArnold yes, he was created, a friend of mine helped with this, the problem was that I had used migration and somehow this was making me unable to create with the Initializer, I deleted the migrations DB then the program start using the seed method and everything else

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all the migration information then the program starts using the Initializer